# Getting 500.0 - Internal Server Error when adding WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX config into web.config

Tags: python, iis, fastapi, uvicorn, wfastcgi

I created a chatbot using FastAPI/Langchain LLM model to create different vector for each user.

The vector created by using ChromaDB, there for loading the vector's file ref into memory.

So whenever the user want to delete a file from their's vector, I need to shudown the current process in able to delete the file (which Chroma keeps in memory) and create new vector base on the left files.

```
    def deleteFile(self, fileName: str) -> ResultViewModel:
        try:
            pathPersist = self.__getPersistPath()
            pathAsset = self.__getAssetPath()
            if (not ChatbotHelper.isExistPath(pathPersist)) or (
                not ChatbotHelper.isExistPath(pathAsset)
            ):
                return ResultViewModel.fail(None, "Doesn't exist this chatbot")

            filePath = pathAsset + f"\\{fileName}"
            os.remove(filePath)

            ChatbotHelper.removeDirectory(pathPersist)
            os.mkdir(pathPersist)

            if len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(self.__getAssetPath()), "*.*")) > 0:
                _ = self.createVectorStore()

            return ResultViewModel.success(None, "Delete file success")
        except Exception as ex:
            return ResultViewModel.fail(None, str(ex))

    def createVectorStore(self):
        VectorstoreIndexCreator(
            vectorstore_kwargs={"persist_directory": self.__getPersistPath()},
            embedding=self.__getVectorEmbedding(),
        ).from_loaders([DirectoryLoader(path=self.__getAssetPath())])
```

and this is in my logger

```
2023-11-27 10:16:14.643167: wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 initialized
2023-11-27 10:16:40.491608: wfastcgi.py exiting because app\persist\cuong\15f1b608-4ee3-48f9-a36e-89a47ac21b5b\header.bin has changed, matching .*(\.py|\.config|\.bin)$
2023-11-27 10:16:40.492608: Running on_exit tasks
```

then the 500 Internal Error happened

this is in my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <add name="FastAPI Handler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite\env\Scripts\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite\env\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite\my_app.log" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="main.wsgi_app" />
        <add key="WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX" value=".*(\.py|\.config|\.bin)$" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

but there're something quite strange, the above code working perfectly on my IIS, but after I restarted to upgrade external disk, this error occured from no-where

Its should have the same behavior as with Uvicorn/FastAPI reload config's mechanism

```
app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    app_str = ("main:app")
    reload_includes = ["*.py", "*.pdf", "*.txt", "*.bin"]
    uvicorn.run(app_str, reload=True, reload_includes=reload_includes)
```

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.